# I am trying to save data in my cluster but Data is not getting saved there

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

```
mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(console.log("Mongo is ON!!"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

//Import model
const project = require('./models/project');
```

What I am trying to do is connect to my atlas and then then save data and find it in to add to my home page ny the cluster in my atlas shows nothing and so do the UI.

This is the save code:

```
//route to save new project
app.post('/createProject', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(path)
    // res.send(req.body);

    const data = new project({
        Name: req.body.Name,
        Description: req.body.Description,
        Author: req.body.Author
    })
    data.save().then(() => {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return res.redirect('back')
    });
})
```

This is to find:

```
app.post('/createProject', (req, res) => {
    return res.redirect('/')
})
//Route to different pages
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    // console.log(path)
    project.find().then(project => {
        // res.render('home');
        console.log(project);
        res.render('home', { project })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));



})
```

But the data is neither updated in cluster nor shown in the UI, like it is not connected here

Comment: How do you even know if the connection to the cluster was successful? Your console.log will immediately execute before the promise is resolved. 
change it to this, .then(() => console.log("Mongo is ON!!"))